# unexpected identifier javascript object method, when I run it I get an error for the first line where I state a function?

Tags: javascript, object

```
var john = {
  fullName: 'John Smith',
  mass: 230 / 2.2,
  height: 1.5
  calcBmi: function(bmi) {
    this.johnBmi = this.height * this.height / this.mass;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a comma after the height. The code becomes (for readability sake):

```
var john = {
    fullName: 'John Smith',
    mass: 230/2.2,
    height: 1.5,
    calcBmi: function(bmi) {
        this.johnBmi = this.height * this.height / this.mass;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a comma after height.

```
var john = { 

fullName: 'John Smith',

mass: 230 / 2.2,

height: 1.5,

calcBmi: function(bmi) {

this.johnBmi = this.height * this.height / this.mass;
}

}
```

Now Try this.